# How do I dynamically create an instance of an object when passed the name of the object as a String? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I have a class library that contains a number of classes. I would like to dynamically create an instance of one of these classes, set its properties, and call a method.

Example:

```
Public Interface IExample
    Sub DoSomething()
End Interface

Public Class ExampleClass
    Implements IExample

    Dim _calculatedValue as Integer

    Public Property calculatedValue() as Integer
        Get
            return _calculatedValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _calculatedValue= value
        End Set
    End Property        

    Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IExample.DoSomething
        _calculatedValue += 5
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Example2
    Implements IExample

    Dim _calculatedValue as Integer

    Public Property calculatedValue() as Integer
        Get
            return _calculatedValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _calculatedValue = value
        End Set
    End Property        

    Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IExample.DoSomething
        _calculatedValue += 7
    End Sub
End Class
```

So, I want to then create code as follows.

```
Private Function DoStuff() as Integer
    dim resultOfSomeProcess as String = "Example2"

    dim instanceOfExampleObject as new !!!resultOfSomeProcess!!! <-- this is it

    instanceOfExampleObject.calculatedValue = 6
    instanceOfExampleObject.DoSomething()

    return instanceOfExampleObject.calculatedValue
End Function
```

Example1 and Example2 may have different properties, which I need to set...

Is this doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) for this. The easiest way (IMO) is to first create a `Type` object and pass that to `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
Dim theType As Type = Type.GetType(theTypename)
If theType IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim instance As IExample = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(theType), IExample)
    ''# use instance
End If
```

Note though that the string containing the type name must contain the full type name, including the namespace.

If you need to access more specialized members on the types, you will still need to cast them (unless VB.NET has incorporated something similar to `dynamic` in C#, which I am not aware of).

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how would I then set the properties of instance without casting it? (as I don't know what to cast it to)

Comment: @tardomatic: excellent question; I was editing that into the answer as you posed it :)

Comment: Small improvements: `Not … Is Nothing` => `… IsNot Nothing`. – `CType` => `DirectCast` (in this case).

Comment: @Konrad: thanks! I have been away from VB.NET for quite some time now, some stuff has obviously faded.

Comment: I was considering some sort of 'object factory' that would return the instance of the class I would like, but this would again leave me without being able to change the properties of the object (and a rather large case statement...) any other ideas as to how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: another idea... I can pass list of values to the constructor when creating the instance using Activator.CreateInstance. The constructor then would map these values to the classes local variables, and I'd be able to call the IExample's methods.